# Ground Plane for Flying Antennas (literally)

Tags: rf, pcb-antenna, lora

I am building a weather balloon sensor baord with a LORA 868 MHz radio module (RFM95x). The sensor will rise up to 30km and should transmit the full time.

I am using a PCB trace antenna with ground plane. For ground applications it is fine to have the antenna on the upper side of the board.

My question A is if I should flip the board upside down to get the ground plane out of the way and have a clear view to the basestation?

Question B is if I flip the antenna (rotate the board), what happens to the polarizastion? Do I have to consider this in the trace (or basestation antenna)? Is this type of PCB antenna the way to go, or should I use an external (dipole) antenna?

Thank you for the help!

868 MHz PCB antenna like this:

[image]

Comment: Use the very best antenna you can afford - have you analysed the path loss at 30 km?

Comment: Yeah ... unfortunately it has to be cheap, so I'd really like to stick to something simple and easy to manufacture. The current record of 868 LoRaWAN is at around 700km in europe. https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/article/lorawan-distance-world-record/ So I hope, considering the good coverage of ground stations to have a connection all the time the balloon rises.

Comment: "should transmit the full time" **it had better not!**   Review the regulations in your location, 868 band has duty cycle limits, additionally an airborne transmitter sending more often than it needs to is quite annoying **over a large geographic area** to other users of a shared band.

Comment: This is not however a particularly suited antenna - it is a compromise for small gadgets.  On a balloon you have plenty of space and could consider a full sized dipole or whip as might be used on a gateway - your enemy is weight not size.  And your receiver in the critical case is more likely on the horizon than "down"

Comment: Thanks Chris, this helps a lot. With "should transmit the full time" I meant "should be able transmit the full time". Of course I will respect the 1% rule. A wire antenna might actually be the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what other analysis you have done, I would recommend doing what you suggested and flip the PCB so that the ground/reference plane is "up" and the radiator is "down".

While you will probably get some performance with the ground plane down, that will be because of RF leakage around the edge of your finite ground plane, and maybe from reflections from objects above the antenna.  If the ground plane were infinite, you would get absolutely nothing (or close to it) on the ground plane side of the antenna.

Did you or anyone else simulate the antenna performance using an E&M tool such as CST Microwave or HFSS?  There are other tools out there, but those are the two that we use for antenna element pattern analysis and design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently we have no simulations for that type but it is proven to work on ground applications. Maybe I'll just give it a try and see how far we get. 
I'm not really in depth with rf circits, but polraization should not be affected, right?

Comment: Jan, if the ground plane is down, then the antenna can *only* emit up. Polarization at that point doesn't matter.

Comment: This seems based on a misunderstanding of the board, there is no ground on the PCB in the area of such an antenna, rather the ground plane is in the area of the PCB containing the components.  So it while it may affect the radiation pattern somewhat it will not function as a shield.  Nor is the receiver likely to be directly below the transmitter for long.

Comment: I was going from this from the OP: "I am using a PCB trace antenna with ground plane. For ground applications it is fine to have the antenna on the upper side of the board"

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Board view is not clear. Actually both sides of the board are on GND. The line below the antenna is the border of that. It is just disabled in this view.